# How does the syntax work for a phrase like "already much too cocky?"

Tags: syntax, syntax-trees, adjectives, adverbs

I'm working on a syntax tree for the sentence "The belief that syntactic theory reveals the inner structure of sentences emboldened the already much too cocky professor," and I'm stuck on "already much too cocky."

As far as I can tell, you can only put one adverb phrase in an adjective phrase, and one adverb in an adverb phrase, but *already*, *much*, and *too* all modify *cocky*, not *professor*.

Am I incorrect in thinking you can only put one adverb in an adverb phrase? Would *already*, *much*, and *too* go in the adverb phrase, in the adjective phrase?*

*In a bracketed diagram, I mean like this: [AdjP[AdvP[already] [much] [too]] [cocky]]

Comment: standard: professor who was already much too cocky. Personally, I do this adjectival extension as a prepended phrase: the already-much too-cocky professor,

Comment: No, they don’t all modify _cocky_ – it’s not ‘already cocky’, ‘much cocky’ and ‘too cocky’. _Too_ modifies _cocky_, _much_ modifies _too cocky_, and _already_ modifies _much too cocky_. More importantly, if your question is about syntax trees, you need to specify what framework you’re working under, since different frameworks draw syntax trees in very different ways.